# Mybatis null configuration object inside custom TypeHandler

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis, typehandler

I was writing a custom `JsonTypeHandler`, code works fine but I wanted access to configuration field of extended `BaseTypeHandler` which seems always null.
Why is it null? Am I missing something here?

[image: null configuration debug image]

Custom JsonTypeHandler: You may ignore methods inside below code.

```
@MappedTypes({ JsonObject.class })
@MappedJdbcTypes({JdbcType.NVARCHAR})
public class JsonTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<JsonObject> {

    private String sqlDialect;

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, JsonObject parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        String parameterAsString = new Gson().toJson(parameter, JsonObject.class);
            ps.setString(i, parameterAsString);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObject getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        String sqlJson = rs.getString(columnName);
        if (null != sqlJson) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(sqlJson, JsonObject.class);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObject getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String sqlJson = rs.getString(columnIndex);
        if (null != sqlJson) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(sqlJson, JsonObject.class);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObject getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String sqlJson = cs.getString(columnIndex);
        if (null != sqlJson) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(sqlJson, JsonObject.class);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL"/>
    </settings>

    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="com.dummy.JsonTypeHandler" javaType="com.google.gson.JsonObject"/>
    </typeHandlers>

    <databaseIdProvider type="DB_VENDOR">
        <property name="PostgreSql" value="postgres"></property>
    </databaseIdProvider>

    <mappers>
        <!--mappers-->
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation"
                  value="classpath:com/dummy/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="postgresDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Versions:

```
dependency 'org.mybatis:mybatis:3.4.1'
mavenBom 'org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.2.6.RELEASE'
```

My intention is to get `databaseId` from configuration object inside `BaseTypeHandler`. Hope snippets are reproducible.

Comment: Mybatis-gson : https://github.com/jneat/mybatis-gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1203), the field `BaseTypeHandler.configuration` is added by mistake and is planned to be removed.

You can register an instance of the type handler after setting necessary properties instead of registering the `Class`.
It would look something like this:

```java
JsonTypeHandler handler = new JsonTypeHandler(configuration);
configuration.getTypeHandlerRegistry().register(..., handler, ...);
```

Comment: ohh, that answer my question. Thanks for the next tip, I will try it out. I was also trying https://github.com/mybatis/spring/issues/218